# Is there any way to use sqlite database in a titanium alloy application for android and i-os both?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am trying to connect an existing SQLite database in Alloy application(MVC for titanium). Can any one suggest any way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy/tree/master/test/apps/models/sql_preload) example for preloading databases in Alloy.